# Transparency Changing Material

Tags: material-science

Is there a material that when exposed to spesific wavelengths of light changes from transparent to opaque in very short time (nanoseconds)?

For example 400nm blue light would change it to transparent and some wavelength of red would make it opaque again. Although some wavelength(s) of light may not make it change in opacity at all.

Comment: Never heard of any such thing, but with some sensors and some active electronics... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pockels_effect#Applications_of_Pockels_cells

Comment: It's called photochromic lenses. [Some companies](https://www.bikeradar.com/news/these-photochromic-lenses-change-faster-than-you-can-say-photochromic/?image=1&type=gallery&gallery=1&embedded_slideshow=1) claims that invented transparency changing glasses with $10~\text{ms}$ response time.

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas, that's five or six magnitudes longer response time than OP was asking for.

Comment: That's why it's not an answer, but a comment. Just a thing to start from. Sure, $ns$ response time would be a hard thing to achieve.